# GSA: index the e-commerce sites and display the results in sort by price?

Tags: meta-tags, google-search, google-search-appliance

We want to index few public e-commerce sites. When our customers search any one of the product the results, should display sort by pricing from all indexed e-commerce sites.

From My Understanding: The public e-commerce sites have different meta tag for pricing i cannot even consolidate into one meta tag. 
Is there possible to Feed via XML, but don't have much idea inside how to achieve? we don't have db access to parse only required data
Via Entity recognition how i can able to index the price as a meta tag ?

Could u please advice us, whether it is achievable or not? If yes, which one is the best solution and refer document for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the sorting issue and just concentrating on normalising the price metadata problem. You need a way to read the price from whatever metadata field it's in and create a new metadata field with a common name and the same value.

There are a few ways to do this but the simplest are probably:

- Generate a Meta-and-url feed for each document and add in the normalised metadata
- Crawl via a proxy that can add a X-GSA-External-Metadata header in containing the normalised metadata

Comment: Hey Mike,Thanks for your comments, surely it will help for me for other projects.  I didn't notice that google has license issue on public sites, that we noticed very recently.                                                                   See "1.1   License Grant." - https://www.google.com/work/gsa/terms_v13.html#

"Customer will only use the Product to create an index of, and to search for, Customer Content."

Comment: As long as you don't use the metadata in dynamic navigation you can use query expansion on meta names for that